# How to change 'with_front" key from an existing custom post type?

Tags: permalinks

I have a CPT called 'experts', that has been created in a theme I bought, and I can't find out where nor where to change it.
I need to change a parameter to 'with_front' => false 
Because my general permaling structure goes with /blog and I do'nt want experts to be in /blog/experts. 
Is there a way I could do that adding something in the functions file?
I have tried this ([How to set "with_front'=>false" to a plugin-generated cpt?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156378/how-to-set-with-front-false-to-a-plugin-generated-cpt)) and various things, but could not get it to work. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try the newly [`register_post_type_args`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/a47fa4f1970996a2aa041ea53a37c4918065cc4b/wp-includes/post.php#L1009-L1018) filter to adjust it.

Here's an untested example:

```
/**
 * Set 'with_front' to false for the 'experts' post type.
 */
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', function( $args, $post_type )
{
    if( 'teachers' === $post_type && is_array( $args ) )
            $args['rewrite']['with_front'] = false;

    return $args;
}, 99, 2 );
```

**Updated** with new info from @Agnes: the post type is `teachers` not `experts`.

Comment: That sounds great, thanks a lot for the suggestion.
However... it does not seem to work. I have added this to functions.php, I have revalidated permalinks, and the experts still come with 'blog/experts'

Comment: YES! With 2 corrections, this works :) 1> I found out the real name of the  plugin generated CPT was teachers and not experts 2> I simplified the IF. Code below.

Comment: NB: I  don't know why defining the specigfic post type does not work.Also, I dont know why it works in parent theme functions file and not child theme.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Note that we must keep the post type check. I did a modification regarding the correct post type `teachers` and temporarily changed the isset check (since with_front is true by default) and changed  the priority to 99. Does this make any difference? @Agnes

Comment: I wonder what is 99 for?

Comment: Great. it's the priority of our filter callback. The default priority is 10. If there are other callbacks for `register_post_type_args`, then our is activated somewhat "late" in the filter chain @Agnes

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, if the CPT has taxonomies associated with it, I've successfully used the following code to rewrite those as well:

```
/**
 * Set 'with_front' to false for the 'portfolio_category' post taxonomy.
 */

add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', function( $args, $taxonomy )
    {
        if( 'portfolio_category' === $taxonomy && is_array( $args ) )
            $args['rewrite']['with_front'] = false;
        return $args;
    }, 99, 2 );
```

In case that is helpful to anyone.

Answer (score -2):

This solution works, added to parent theme functions.php:

```
        add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', function( $args, $post_type )
        {
            $args['rewrite']['with_front'] = false;
            return $args;
        }, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Your code will affect to all post types. Not recommended.