# How to apply wordpress 'with_front' = false for categories?

Tags: categories

I know that how to add add `'with_front' = false` for WordPress custom taxonomy when adding them.

But how to apply WordPress `'with_front' = false` for categories?

Comment: This should help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/228590/2807

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`register_taxonomy_args` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_taxonomy_args/) should do the job intercepting the arguments for the specified taxonomy:

```
add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', 'cyb_modify_category_args', 99, 2 );
function cyb_modify_category_args( $args, $taxonomy ) {
    if( 'category' === $taxonomy && is_array( $args ) ) {
            $args['rewrite']['with_front'] = false;
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: I have never seen that passing something like `function( $args, $taxonomy )` to a filter. Please can you explain little more how this work? What is the meaning of `function( $args, $taxonomy )`

Comment: They are called [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), you can use whatever you want, anonymous functions or named functions, but anonymous functions are not recommend for filters and actions hooks if your code is for public release because they makes [very difficult to unnregister them](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137688/remove-actions-filters-added-via-anonymous-functions) if someone wants to do it.

Comment: Answer updated using named function as callback, just in case you feel more comfortable.